# Measurable function of a transformation still measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking for a maybe simpler or more elemental proof of the following statement:

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be (Lebesgue-)measurable.
Then $F:\mathbb{R^{2n}}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x,y)=f(x-y)$ is (Lebesgue-)measurable.

The proof I know works in the following way:
First show that $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R^{2n}}$.
Then $T(x,y)=(x-y)$ is Lipschitz and hence $f\circ T$ is measurable (by a theorem ).

Can one somehow argue without the Lipschitz continuity in the last step or with a different ansatz? Several books I've seen introduce the convolution using that $f(x-y)$ is measurable but proof that Lipschitz $T$ maps measurable sets onto measurable sets later in the text.

Comment: I'm curious how you would extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. If I remember correct, it has been dealt in one of Rudin's books, probably "Real and Complex Analysis".

Comment: It could be like the following: Define $G(x,y):=f(x)$, then $\{(x,y): G>a\}=\{(x,y): f(x)>a\}= \{x :f(x)> a\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and the last set is measurable on the product space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so this is as elementary and intuitive as I could think of. We assume only that if $U \subset R^n$ is measurable and $T$ is a rotation on $R^n$, then $T(U)$ is measurable. This is a standard fact about the Lebesgue measure and should be covered quite early in most books. For simplicity, consider $n = 1$.

Define $G:R^2 \to R$ by $G(x,y) = y-x$. Since $F^{-1}(U) = G^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ for each $U \in R$ and $f$ is assumed measurable, we only have to show that $G^{-1}(U) \subset R^2$ is measurable for each measurable $U \subset R$ in order to prove that $F$ is measurable.

If $U = \{c\}$ consists of a single point, then
$$G^{-1}(\{c\}) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y-x = c\} = \{(x,x+c)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

which is the graph of the function $y(x) = x + c$. The slope of this function is $1$ which corresponds to an angle with the $x$-axis of $45$ degrees.

If we let $T: R^2 \to R^2$ be the linear transformation that rotates clockwise by $45$ degrees, then

$$T(G^{-1}(\{c\})) = T(\{(x,x+c)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{R}\}) = \{(x,c) \in R^2: x \in R\}$$

Now if $U \subset R$ is measurable, then
$$U = \bigcup_{c \in U} \{c\}$$
which means that
$$T(G^{-1}(U)) = \bigcup_{c \in U} T(G^{-1}(\{c\})) = \bigcup_{c \in U}T(\{(x,x+c)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{R}\})$$
$$ = \bigcup_{c \in U}\{(x,c) \in R^2: x \in R\} = R \times U$$

which is the product of two measurable sets and hence measurable (by definition).
Thus
$$G^{-1}(U) = T^{-1}T(G^{-1}(U))$$
is measurable since $T^{-1}$ is also a rotation.

Comment: so considering my first comment after the question you have directly shown that the set $\{(x,y): f(x-y)> a\}= \{\xi: f(\xi)> a\}\times R^n$ for appropriate coordinates $\xi$ (and maybe one additional coordinate). And you have achieved this,  exploiting essentially that the Lebesgue measure is rotation/translation invariant, right?

Comment: I found some lecture note, where the translation and rotation invariance of the Lebesgue measure is proven exploiting that Lipschitz functions map measurable sets on measurable sets. However Rudin's book on real and complex analysis proves the invariance "directly".

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Regarding the first comment: pretty much. We didn't have to do quite as much, because by the measurability of $f$, $\{x: f(x) > a\}$ is already measurable. So what was left to show was that $\{(x,y): x-y \in A\}$ is measurable for any measurable set $A$ in $R$.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Regarding the second comment. Perfect, Rudin is also the book I refer back to for these questions. Rudin goes through quite some labor to prove this and more in Chapter 2. But if you only care about rotations of measurable sets being measurable you can repeatedly apply Rudin's Theorem 1.8 and the comments following it to get what you want using much less machinery!

Comment: thanks for the hint on theorem 1.8. Nice idea

Answer (score -1):

The rotation technique needs to be preceded by a translation to the origin, and then shifted back. If you rotate the line y=x+1 by 45 degrees, it doesn't become parallel to the x axis unless you do this shifting stuff...

Comment: Wrong. The angle after rotation depends only on the angular data.